# Error splicing files when copying from NAS

Tags: ubuntu, nas, cifs

This is a desperation repost of [this issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2449712) I created way back in the Ubuntu forums and never fixed.

I'm getting this error message while copying files from my Samba/Cifs NAS to my drive. I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 using Nemo 4.4.2

```
Error while copying 'filename'
There was an error copying the file into '/destination'
Error splicing file: Input/output error
```

cp also yields an error

```
cp /media/NAS\ Storage/file .
cp: error reading '/media/NAS Storage/file': Input/output error
```

I can now report that the second disk I just installed does the same

More info & more weirdness:

- Another machine with Ubuntu & Nautilus has the same problem
- But my Windows machine does not
- Files are partially copied but miss the last few MBs.
- Opening files from my NAS in the appropriate program works fine.
- FTP and rsync work fine
- This is my fstab

```
# Nas Storage "Volume_1" on 192.168.1.140
//192.168.1.140/Volume_1    /media/NAS\040Storage        cifs    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Note: the second machine has no blank spaces in the mount point, and it still doesn't work

- I can upload files to the NAS, copy from NAS to itself fine
- Small files almost always work, large ones rarely (>500MB)

Since then I ran through every option in the manual to see if there was a better way to mount, including

- serverino, noserverino
- soft, hard
- nounix

What can I do? How can i at least obtain a more detailed error message?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having similar issues with my Netgear NAS. In my case, the NAS is ancient and only supports SMB1. Copying files TO the NAS is fine but FROM the NAS is hit and miss like you.

Comment: Nope, my theory is that kernel support for SMB1 is broken. I never got around to filing a bug report, though, as I didn't do enough tests to be sure.

Comment: I agree. On the same machine, I have a Windows VM, that works perfectly. This seems to tell me it's related to the protocol for SMB.

Answer (score 0):

Follwing settings solved it for me. My client machine is Linux Mint 21 (ubuntu 22.04 based) system, kernel 5.14.21. File server is Apple Time Capsule 4th gen on firmware 7.8.1. I had this issue also in Mint 20.3 (ubuntu 20.04 based), kernel 5.4.0.120.

```bash
sudo mount //tc.local/apdata /mnt/tc/apdata -t cifs -o "cred=/home/ganesh/.apcred,domain=WORKGROUP,ip=10.0.1.1,servern=tc,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,noposix,cache=strict,rwpidforward,noserverino,nosetuids,actimeo=3"
```

You may want to tune actimeo= option upto 30 seconds. It basically tells client to not reload meta data too often which makes some copy programs misbehave.

You may want to check "man mount.cifs" to get an idea of above options.

Also check your client machine's dmesg output to make sure your source drive is not failing with read IO errors.